# How to load strings from sharedpreferences in EditText

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am very new to this and hate to add so much code but I've spent so much time on this I am out of choices. I have an activity/page that saves some userdetails. Now, I am trying to save these details so that next time when they open the activity/page the data shows up.

I've tried doing this by starting a loadSavedPreferences method in the oncreate method. However, this is not working and if I go back to the frontpage and reenter this activity it's all gone again.  Answers in code would be greatly appreciated.

JAVA:

```
public class my_settings extends Activity {

EditText name;
EditText email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_settings);
    name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    loadSavedPreferences();
}

public void save(View view)
{
    SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("UserDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=userDetails.edit();
    editor.putString("storedName",name.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("storedEmail",email.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

    Toast.makeText(this,"Data was saved succesfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences userDetails = referenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String tempName = userDetails.getString("storedName", "Name");  // (key, default)
    String tempEmail = userDetails.getString("storedEmail","Email Address");
    name.setText(tempName);
    email.setText(tempEmail);

}
}
```

The XML code looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jesper.im_ok.my_settings"
android:clickable="false">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please enter contact details here:"
    android:id="@+id/settings_title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:clickable="false"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name of Contact"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/settings_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:text="Email Address"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In save method, you are using `getSharedPreferences("UserDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` which is user created SharedPreferences table and
2. While accessing the data in you are trying to get values from defaultSharedPreferences which is default one provided by android. This is wrong.

try this in loadSavedPreferences

`SharedPreferences userDetails = this.getSharedPreferences("UserDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Hope this helps!!

Comment: That's it! Haha, can't see the forest for the trees. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences userDetails = this.getSharedPreferences("UserDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String tempName = userDetails.getString("storedName", "Name");  // (key, default)
    String tempEmail = userDetails.getString("storedEmail","Email Address");
    name.setText(tempName);
    email.setText(tempEmail);
}
```

test this

Answer (score 0):

To put values in your shared preferences  you need call the method edit "pref.edit().putString..."

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences pref               = null;
    private final String      SETTINGS_PREF_NAME = "UserDetails";
    EditText                  email;

    EditText                  name;

    public void save( final View view ) {
        this.pref = this.getSharedPreferences( this.SETTINGS_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS );

        this.pref.edit().putString( "storedName", this.name.getText().toString() ).commit();
        this.pref.edit().putString( "storedEmail", this.email.getText().toString() ).commit();

        Toast.makeText( this, "Data was saved succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        this.setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        this.loadSavedPreferences();
    }

    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        final String tempName = this.pref.getString( "storedName", "Name" ); // (key, default)
        final String tempEmail = this.pref.getString( "storedEmail", "Email Address" );
        this.name.setText( tempName );
        this.email.setText( tempEmail );

    }
}
```